# Visual Studio 2019 is not detected by Github extension

Tags: visual-studio, github

After running Github extension for VS while my Visual Stuio is still running, I received the error message below. I appreciate some guidance how to resolve this.

---

Maybe my question should be: if Github is already built-in, I do not see the "Clone Repo" button when I click the Source Control icon on the lefthand-side of the VS window. This is true even when I'm already signed in to Github within VS.

---

```
>  Microsoft VSIX Installer
>          -------------------------------------------
>         vsixinstaller.exe version:
>         
>         Command line parameters:
>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\Jim\GitHub.VisualStudio-v2.11.106.vsix
>         
>          Microsoft VSIX Installer
>         Skipping product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools (7670aa47) since it does not support extensions
>         Initializing Install...
>          Extension Details...
>         Identifier         : c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc
>         Name               : GitHub Extension for Visual Studio
>         Author             : GitHub, Inc
>         Version            : 2.11.106.19330
>         Description        : A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
>         Locale             : en-US
>         MoreInfoURL        : https://visualstudio.github.com/
>     
>     InstalledByMSI     : False
>     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
>     
>     SignatureState     : ValidSignature
>     SignedBy           : GitHub, Inc.
>     Certificate Info   : 
>     [Subject]       : CN="GitHub, Inc.", O="GitHub, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US
>     [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
>     [Serial Number] : 09144B52C8330F257D2512DAAAA1E545
>     [Not Before]    : 5/2/2020 8:00:00 AM
>     [Not After]     : 9/2/2023 8:00:00 PM
>     [Thumbprint]    : 9C5A6D389E1454F2ED9EE9419CDF743689709F9C
>     
>     Supported Products : 
>     Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
>     Version : [14.0,17.0)
>     
>     References         : 
>     Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0
>           Name         : Visual Studio MPF 14.0
>     Version      : [14.0,)
>     MoreInfoURL  : 
>     Nested       : No
>     
>     Prerequisites      : 
>     Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
>     Name         : Visual Studio core editor
>     Version      : [15.0.25824.0,)
>     
>     Signature Details...
>     Extension is signed with a valid signature.
>     
>     Searching for applicable products...
>     Found installed product - Global Location
>     VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
>        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension
> extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported,
> IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
>        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported,
> IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
>        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData
> stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
>        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData
> stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
>        at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
>        at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
>        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
> exceptionObject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github support is now built in the VS2019. You probably have a conflict between the built-in version and your extension. You can safely uninstall your extension.

Did you get it from the marketplace? Those are okay to install while VS is running, they just tell you to restart afterwards. If it's a third-party extensions, installing it while VS is running is probably not a good idea.

Otherwise:

- Make sure you have the latest version of VS2019 (16.10.1 as of this post).
- Check `Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection` is set to `Git`.
- More options will then appear below `Plug-in Selection` that will allow you to set up global and per-repository/solution settings.

The repository window is no longer Source Control or Team Explorer for Git integration. It's been migrated to two panel windows: `View > Git Changes` and `View > Git Repository` along with an entire menu bar item `Git` located next to `View`.

Comment: Thanks Casey but when i go to VS' Source Control icon on the lefthand side of the window, it says "no source control providers registered" while i'm signed in to Github within VS. I read that i'm supposed to see buttons with "Open Folder" and "Clone Repository" but mine is totally empty.

how do i even get started to link VS to my Github Repo?

Comment: @JimBoyLim Just to be clear, you are talking about Visual Studio, NOT Visual Studio Code, right? They are two different products.

Comment: Yes Visual Studio. i think i have Visual Studio 2021 and when i click "clone repository" from the Welcome Screen,  i'm getting "it looks like Git is not installed in your system"

Comment: @JimBoyLim Visual Studio 2021 is not a thing and Visual Studio 2022 Preview 1 is not out yet; you likely have Visual Studio 2019. Anyway, close VS, then run the visual studio installer > click Modify > then Individual components > scroll down to Code Tools > confirm that  `Git for Windows` and `Github extension for VIsual Studio` are checked. *Unless* you installed git outside of visual studio. Mine are not checked because I use a third-party Git client/GUI, GitKraken.

Comment: thanks Casey, i reinstalled VS since it  does not show any "Modify" option. But this solved the problem. Thanks again. I just need a way to figure out again how to reinstate my SQL database links....